# WiX Bundle with dynamic MsiPackage names

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I'm converting our current monolithic installer to use a WiX 3.7 Bundle/chain.  We have several components that are now building into their own separately-maintainable MSI installers.  My next task is to add all of these to a bootloader/bootchainer, but I've hit a snag.

A requirement for our individual installers is that they contain the version in the filename (i.e. MyApplication-5.4.22.msi).  I don't see a tool like Heat for collecting MSI packages together, and I don't see a way to add an MsiPackage element with a wildcard to account for varying package names.

As a last resort, I can wrap the bundler inside of another MSBuild script that will 'autocomplete' the filenames and pass the paths in as variables to the bundler.  I'm hoping someone can recommend a solution that works directly in the wxs or wixproj setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the msi files are built with WiX Setup projects, the WiX Bootstrapper project can reference them, thereby creating useful WiX variables that are defined as the paths to the msi files.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18679013/2226988), as well as the list of variables [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html).

If that's not the case then you can write some MSBuild targets that run [before](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee216359%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the Build target to figure out the actual file paths. If the available standard and community MSBuild tasks aren't sufficient, you can write [your own tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), either by creating an assembly or using [inline code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). (And, of course, there is always the [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) task to shell out to a command-line program like cmd.exe, after which you can parse its output to extract the msi paths.)

Comment: The installers are pre-built, so I can't simply reference their wixproj files.  Currently I'm creating an MSBuild ItemGroup for each installer so that I can use the builtin wildcard functionality.  As far as I can tell, placing the version in the msi filename is a fairly standard practice, so I was hoping that WiX would have some sort of support for automating this process.

Comment: I don't see how WiX could do it any more succinctly than with an MSBuild ItemGroup and there is no point in duplicating MSBuild.

Comment: I think you're right.  I was hoping to avoid the hassle that is passing multiple variables into a WXS file via DefineConstants.  I can only imagine this being confusing for future maintainers, but it really is the most straightforward method.  I wish wxs files could access msbuild properties directly.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Many developers never think of looking into the project files. I have left them hints in the Before Build Event like "REM Look in the project file for build customizations"; Could use ECHO instead of REM, too. Or, you could use an MSBuild import so the customizations are in an external file that can be added so it is visible in the project. (Downside there is that VS won't apply any changes made to the file until after the project is reloaded.)